# How to remove remote tags not on my local repository?

Tags: regex, git, bash, grep

I would like to have origin match my local tags. This is not to be confuse with pruning local tags, but remote instead.

To prune **local** tags and make my local repository match origin I do:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch
```

I cleaned the tags locally and I would like to push and remove what is not up in remote.

I have been doing it manually like:

```
git tag -l | grep -v "[^v2]" | xargs git tag -d  # remove local tags that don't match a pattern
git push origin :refs/tags/2.2.15      # manually remove those tags on remote
git push origin :refs/tags/2.2.16
git push origin :refs/tags/2.2.17
git push origin :refs/tags/2.2.18
...
```

But with so many tag I feel like this could be done differently.
Question is then, How to remove from a remote repository those tags that you do not have locally?

Comment: Does [this](http://blog.siyelo.com/how-to-bulk-delete-remote-git-tags/) help?

Comment: Yeap, I think so... git ls-remote --tags origin | awk '/^(.*)(\s+)(.*[a-z])$/ {print ":" $2}' | xargs git push origin

Comment: `git ls-remote --tags origin | grep -v "[{}$]" | awk '{print ":" $2}'`

I haven't been able to test the removal, but that command shows a very promising output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it on a remote repo and it works fine.

I used `cut` instead of `grep`, and compared the remote tags against the local ones, then removed the remote ones that differed.

```
git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f 2 | xargs basename | comm -23 - <(git tag) | awk '{print ":refs/tags/" $0}'  | xargs git push origin
```

Not the most elegant thing in the world, but it works.